# SQL to find sum of column

Tags: sql, sum, self-join

I have a table insurance with columns:

```
p_id smallint
2011_inv int
2012_inv int
city char(15)
```

I want to find out sum total of `2012_inv` for all p_id where `2011_inv` is equal but city name is different. Please help. I have been struggling with this all evening.

Refer to the table below

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you would want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(tiv_2012) FROM insurance
WHERE tiv_2011 = tiv_2012
AND city NOT 'value';
```

City is different from what? There needs to be a value for City for it to be different from something